# What is the renormalization factor of the fixed particle number BCS wave function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

The BCS wavefunction, with fixed number is written as

$$\left|\Psi_{BCS}(N)\right\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\phi\, e^{-iN\phi/2} \left|\Psi_{BCS}(\phi)\right\rangle \,\, ,$$

where:
$$\left|\Psi_{BCS}(\phi)\right\rangle = \left( |u_k| + e^{i\phi} |v_k| c_{k\uparrow}^{\dagger} c_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}\right) \left|0\right\rangle $$.

Is this wavefunction normalized given $\left|\Psi_{BCS}(\phi)\right\rangle$ is normalized? If not, what is the normalization constant?

Comment: What are your attempts?